# How to sort SOLR spellCheck suggestions NOT by frequency?

Tags: solr, spell-checking

If you search for **ahve** on my staging index you get **the** as the first spellcheck correction because **the** appears more than **have** in the index (I have 500 documents indexed).
If you search for **ahve** on my local index you get **have** as the first spellcheck correction because **have** appears more than any other word in the index. (I have 21 documents indexed).
This is a simple dumb returned from my staging index

```
<lst name="ahve">
<int name="numFound">5</int>
<int name="startOffset">0</int>
<int name="endOffset">4</int>
<int name="origFreq">0</int>
<arr name="suggestion">
<lst>
<str name="word">the</str>
<int name="freq">112</int>
</lst>
<lst>
<str name="word">are</str>
<int name="freq">67</int>
</lst>
<lst>
<str name="word">have</str>
<int name="freq">44</int>
</lst>
<lst>
<str name="word">acne</str>
<int name="freq">10</int>
</lst>
<lst>
<str name="word">ache</str>
<int name="freq">3</int>
</lst>
</arr>
</lst>
```

And adding `spellcheck.onlyMorePopular=true` or `spellcheck.onlyMorePopular=false` does NOT change anything.
Is there a way not to sort the returned suggestions by frequency of appearance?

Comment: Is there any way to replace **freq** of suggestion with user-defined field ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, spellcheck results are returned based on the Levenshtein string distance formula and then frequency, or the frequency and then score.

You can specify your own sorting method by writing a custom comparator that implements `Comparator`. Then, provide the name of that method to the field `comparatorClass` in your solrconfig.xml.

```
<lst name="spellchecker">
  <str name="name">freq</str>
  <str name="field">lowerfilt</str>
  <str name="spellcheckIndexDir">spellcheckerFreq</str>
  <!-- comparatorClass be one of:
     1. score (default)
     2. freq (Frequency first, then score)
     3. A fully qualified class name
   -->
  <str name="comparatorClass">my.custom.ComparatorClass</str>
  <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
</lst>
```

A couple more suggestions:

- The field `spellcheck.onlyMorePopular` doesn't affect sort ordering. This field checks the query results for each suggestion, and displays only the suggestions with the most query results, *even if the correct suggestion exists*. Use with caution.
- Make sure to remove stopwords such as 'the', 'that', etc, by passing in your data through the `StopFilterFactory` on both the index and query side of your requestHandler.

See: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent for more information.

Comment: Just to clarify - ahve->have has a LD (Levenshtein distance) of 2 and ahve->the have the same distance (try http://planetcalc.com/1721/)