# Sort Solr returned result in spellchecker by edit distance

Tags: solr, spell-checking

I'm using spell checker on Solr. And I want to sort the returned result by Edit Distance, not by frequency.

For example I have the term "anp". I mistyped into "apn" and the result was like the following order:

```
<str>plan</str>
<str>anp</str>
<str>cacc</str>
```

And I want the "anp" will be first that shown in the result because the distance between "apn" and "anp" is shorter than "apn" and "plan".

My field in this case is multivalue.

**UPDATE:**

I have changed it to multivalue=false so It can be easier in sorting but It still stay the same. Anyone who knows about the ordering of returned result please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13490270/how-to-sort-solr-spellcheck-suggestions-not-by-frequency
Have you tried this one ?

Comment: Still stay the same. The order is still the same. Don't know why it is like that. Maybe I'm just stupid.